# Ruby class based on BasicObject can't access code in other module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-1.9

I'm using `method_missing` to define a class for namespacing constants in a vocabulary. To be effective, I need the vocabulary class to inherit from `BasicObject`, otherwise none of the standard object methods are available as vocabulary terms (because the method isn't missing :). However, when I inherit from `BasicObject`, I find I can't call utility methods in another module. The following code illustrates the issue in condensed form:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.fubar( s )
      "#{s} has been fubar'd"
    end
  end
end

class V1
  def self.method_missing( name )
    Foo::Bar.fubar( "#{name} in v1" )
  end
end

class V2 < BasicObject
  def self.method_missing( name )
    Foo::Bar.fubar( "#{name} in v2" )
  end
end

# this works
puts V1.xyz
# => xyz in v1 has been fubar'd

# this doesn't
puts V2.xyz
# => NameError: uninitialized constant V2::Foo
```

What would I need to add to `V2` so that it doesn't produce an unitialized constant error when I try to call the helper module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you change the method in `V2` like this so that name resolution starts in the global scope.

```
def self.method_missing( name )
  ::Foo::Bar.fubar( "#{name} in v2" )
end
```

I looked it up in [the documentation for you](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject):

> BasicObject does not include Kernel (for methods like puts) and
>   BasicObject is outside of the namespace of the standard library so
>   common classes will not be found without a using a full class path.
>   ...
>   Access to classes and modules from the Ruby standard library can be
>   obtained in a BasicObject subclass by referencing the desired constant
>   from the root like ::File or ::Enumerator.